# Call function inside a function in a class from another function in another class in Python

Tags: python, function, class

How can I call function `f2` from `f1` method in `class A` from `f3` method in `class B` which inherited from `class A`?

```
class A():
    def f1(self):
        return 'f1'
        def f2(self, x):
            return 'f2' + str(x)


class B(A):
    def f3(self):
        # Call f1 method work fine
        self.y = self.f1()
        # Call f2 method won't work
        self.z = self.f1.f2('XoXo')
        return 'f3' + self.y + self.z


b = B()
print(b.f3())
```

I expect the output to be `'f3f1f2XoXo'`, but I got this error:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'f2'

Comment: You can't. `f2` is not available to any parent namespace

Comment: `f2` is local to `f1`, so you can't refer to it from outside. What would be your real use case for such a structure?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I want to reuse `f2` function again in another class without repeat my code again. So should I copy `f2` function in `class B`?

Comment: Why is f2 declared inside f1 to start with ? There are various possible solution but you really don't provide enough context to properly answer your question.

Comment: NB: the most obvious solution being, of course, to extract f2 as a top-level standalone function....

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks for the reply. I define `f2` inside `f1` because it's related to this method. So if there is no way to use `f2` function again somewhere in my code I must define it as a method of `class A`.

Comment: "it's related to this method" is a bit vague - and unless you need a closure (which doesn't seem to be the case), this isn't a good reason to nest the function. Also, you only want to make it a method if it needs access to the current instance (and even then - the current instance (`self`) is just an argument amongst others). Python is not Java and doesn't require you to put all your code in methods, plain functions are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class A():
    def f1(self):
        def f2(self, x):
            return 'f2' + str(x)
        return 'f1', f2(self, 'XoXo')


class B(A):
    def f3(self):
        self.x = self.f1()
        self.y = self.x[0]
        self.z = self.x[1]
        return 'f3' + self.y + self.z


b = B()
print(b.f3())
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want to do ?

```
class A():
    def f1(self):
        return 'f1'
    def f2(self, x):
        return 'f2' + str(x)


class B(A):
    def f3(self):
        # Call f1 method work fine
        self.y = self.f1()
        # Call f2 method won't work
        self.z = self.f1() + self.f2(1)
        return 'f3' + self.y + self.z


b = B()
print(b.f3())
```

Comment: The fact that the OP tried to call `self.f1.f2` seems to indicate that he really meant to declare `f2` inside `f1`, not as another method of `A`